# Is there any plugin in angularjs , such as when session out user should ask for login credentials

Tags: java, angularjs, spring

Looking for angularjs plugin , i,e when user session out then login page should come and when user again login then he should again logged in to the same page where he has left. I have used spring security for login.
Can anybody help me ?

Comment: You can run a function on certain time interval that will invoke a url to validate session. if session expired than mask tha main page with message. I don't think there is a ready made plugin.

Comment: Did you have a dedicated login page that is not part of your angularjs of app?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a technique demonstrated by the [CRM sample of Civilian](http://www.civilian-framework.org/doc-samples.html#crm): It uses

- a Angular Client
- a REST server, should be applicable to your scenario

When the server session had a timeout, then any subsequent Ajax call by the client will be answered with HTTP 401 Unauthorized.

The Angular client installed a HTTP interceptor which detects the 401 response, and transparently shows a modal login box. When they users entered its credentials they are sent to a login URL to the server which then establishes a new session. After such a successful re-login, the original request (which failed with a 401) is resent.

So the rest of the application is totally unaware of this mechanism, it is completely transparent.

The HTTP interceptor is available as own [Angular module](https://github.com/jdlib/civilian/blob/master/src/js/civassets/angular/civ-auth.js).